# Hide field based on checkbox using javascript in odoo 12

Tags: javascript, checkbox, hide, odoo

I have two fields, field1 is a checkbox and field2 is a normal text field. I want to hide a field2 if a field1 is not checked and if

field1 is checked then show field2. For that, I am creating the following code:

```
odoo.define('survey_inherit.FormView', function (require) {
"use strict";

var FormView = require('web.FormView');
var core = require('web.core');
var QWeb = core.qweb;

var FormView = FormView.extend({
   _checkField: function(){

        var $checkbox = $('.custom-control-input').val();

        if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {

        $('.o_form_label').show();
        $('.mandatory_msg_class').show();
        }else{

          $('.mandatory_msg_class').hide();
        }//close else
   },
});//close FormController

return FormView; 
});
```

But field2 is not hidden if field1 is not checked and also field2 is not shown if field1 is checked.

**Update**

My requirement is that I have one form which contains a one2many field with widget many2many_tags and other fields. After clicking on tags of many2many_tags, I want to display the complete records in other fields. I am able to get complete records after a click on tags and also these records are able to put in other fields. After using attrs and opening form view for creating records field2 will never display. But open form view in edit mode after creating a record and click on many2many_tags 
field2 is not displayed because of attrs.
Removing attrs and opening form view for creating records field will display(but don't want to display because field1 is not checked) and open form view in edit mode after creating a record, click on many2many_tags work fine as expected.
Attrs condition: attrs=**"{'invisible':[('constr_mandatory','!=',True)]}"**
constr_ mandatory: checkbox field
This is the reason I am not using attrs and trying to achieve with the help of javascript. I hope the provided information is understood. Also, I have updated the question added screenshots for better understanding.

Using attrs:[image]

Using attrs click on many2many_tags
[image]

Without using attrs:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new widget and override the `click` method.

I did this with a `BooleanToggle` field.

```
var basic_fields = require('web.basic_fields');

var Toggle = basic_fields.BooleanToggle.extend({

    _onClick: function (event) {
        var self = this;
        this._super(event);
        var node = event.view.$('.custom-control-input');

        if(this.value) {
            node.show();
        } else {
            node.hide();
        }
    },
});

fieldRegistry.add('toggle', Toggle);
```

You need to add the widget attribute:

```
field name="field1" widget="toggle"/>
```

**Edit**
You need to hide the fields after the form loaded, I suggest to you to override the `autofocus` function of the `FormRenderer`.

```
var FormRenderer = require('web.FormRenderer');
FormRenderer.include({
    autofocus: function () {
        var self = this;
        // In my test I used fields values available in "self.state.data"
        if(self.state.model === 'sale.order' && field_value){
            var nodes = window.$('.custom-control-input');
            nodes.hide();
        }
        return this._super();
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Kenly for an answer. your answer works properly after the event occurs but at the initial toggle is off at that time I want to hide another field. How this is done? can you please suggest?

Comment: If you need to hide a field based on another field value, why not using attrs?

Comment: I make use of attrs it works fine. but for some condition, it didn't work. Therefore I am trying to achieve using javascript.

Comment: Add more details about the conditions where `attrs` did not work and we will figure out how to make it work

Comment: Hello @Kenly, sorry for the late reply. I have updated my question. For attrs condition can you please check, because the comment section allow only for specific number of characters.

Comment: So you need to show `error_message` field only when `constr_mandatory` is checked?

Comment: You will need to hide fields after the view has loaded, hide them when a user clicks on the checkbox and when the edit button is clicked.But it can be done easily with `attrs`.`<field name="constr_mandatory"/><field name="error_message" attrs="{'invisible': [('constr_mandatory', '=', False)]}"/>`

Comment: Yes, the answer given is right. But in the form view, there is one field(Questions) this is one2many field with many2many_tag. After clicking on the edit button form is open in edit mode. Click on tags of Questions field I want to edit records of tag, for that, in form view questions field are taken.

Comment: Now Consider If I am using attrs and after a click on tags contain records and also the question(tag) is mandatory it will open all tags records in question fields but error_message is not shown.

Comment: attrs is not working, if I want to edit Question field tags. the attrs are working for the creation of question, not for edit answers. For a clear understanding, I have attached a screenshot as Using attrs click on many2many_tags

Comment: do you need to show the `error message` when you select a question in `Questions` tags that require an answer?

Comment: Forget about all these things. Just see the third screenshot i.e Without using attrs in that mandatory answer is not selected still showing error_message. I want to achieve this using javascript not using attrs. I am able to achieve other things.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I did not understand your requirement. Check my edit.The above code is tested with a boolean field in sale order form view.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Both solutions provided by you is helpful for me. both working as I want. Thank You so much. Also thank you for your valuable time and solution. :)

Comment: I have one question is it also possible to hide labels?

Comment: Yes, of course, In my case, I used `parent()` twice to hide the `TR` which contains two `TD`(The first one contains the label). The field is added to the form view inside the `group` tag. It depends on the FormView arch. After getting your `custom input` you will just need to get the `closest` label using JQUERY.

Comment: How to get the closest label using JQUERY? because I am trying to hide label using jquery as $('.o_form_label').hide(), but all labels in the form view will be hidden.

Comment: Try with `window.$('.custom-control-input').parent().parent()` and you can use `find` to get only the label.

Answer (score 0):

`var $checkbox = $('.custom-control-input').val();`

This line set `$checkbox` to the checkbox's value. May be you just want the checkbox element itself:

```
var $checkbox = $('.custom-control-input');
```

Comment: thanks, @thanhdx for your replay. but the field is not shown or hidden.

Comment: @sss It should work in Odoo the same as in JQuery. You might face other errors due to element existent/query/styling, etc. Go debug and find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selpoNO").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(".if_pucEntry").show();
    } else {
      $(".if_pucEntry").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- checkbox -->
<label class="led-label"><input type="checkbox" class="led-btn" name="selpoNO" id="selpoNO" style="width: auto !important;"><strong>Checkbox</strong></label>

<!-- text box -->

<input type="text" class="form-control if_pucEntry" id="" name="" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: thanks, @Joe for your replay. but the field is not shown or hidden. I want to do this in odoo 12.